# howto: Add calendar item to user's calendar fromout website?

Tags: android, ios, url, calendar

we have this webpage, which detects which mobile OS the user uses. The user must click on a link 'save to my calendar' to add a specific item to his calendar, automatically.

We want to configure this link for Android and iPhone.

What are the url's we have to use so when they hit this link, the item will be set in to their Android or iOS calendar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried generating an ics file?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but won't load the Android calendar

Comment: Indeed, just discovered it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31894